# setting custom UITableViewCell selector

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, selector

I have created a custom `UITableViewCell` that is added as a subview to my view. In this view there is also a a `UITableView`. The custom `UITableViewCell` is not part(included) into the `UITableView`.

I have set the custom `UITableViewCell` up in my viewDidLoad method like this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Create custom tableviewCell at top of screen under navigation controller

    cellContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 44.0)];
    cellContainer.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UITableViewCell *mycell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 50.0)];
    mycell.textLabel.text = @"Select all";
    mycell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


    [cellContainer addSubview:mycell];
    [self.view insertSubview:cellContainer atIndex:1];

    // Set table positioning
    [subModelTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 44)];
    [self.view insertSubview:subModelTableView atIndex:0];

    // set tableview datasource and delegate
    [subModelTableView setDelegate:self];
    [subModelTableView setDataSource:self];
}
```

The thing being at the moment I am unable to select this custom tableview cell, I have tried to set a selector on it like this

```
[mycell addTarget:self action:@selector(myAwesomeMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

but I am getting an error

```
No visible @interface for 'UITableViewCell' declares the selector 'addTarget:action:forControlEvents:'
```

So I would like to know if there is either another way of doing this (proper way) or if I am on the right track how can I resolve this error?

EDIT:
The reason I have this extra `UITableViewCell` in this view is that it sits below the `UINavigationBar` as a static cell with @"Select all" in it, this cell sits above the `UITableView` but gives the appeance of being included in the `UITableView` but obviously is not.

When the user scrolls the `UITableView` of values if the user dose not know which cell he would like to select I want to enable the @"Select all" cell, so he receives a list of values that would represent selecting every cell in the `UITableView`. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: try [mycell.contentView addTarget...]

Comment: still giving me an error, even cleaned the project after putting that in the error is different but still the same.. **No visible @interface for 'UIView' declares the selector 'addTarget:action:forControlEvents:'**

Comment: Yup, addTarget is a UIControl class method, so you can only do this on views descendant from UIControl (like UIButton).  You'll need to look at handling raw touch events...

Comment: okay so maybe I have to replace it with a UIButton and just make it look like a UITableViewCell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I would like to know if there is either another way of doing this
>   (proper way) or if I am on the right track how can I resolve this
>   error?

I don't think this is the correct way to do it. I think you should use the UITableViewDelegate's didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.  If this isn't going to work, then please elaborate on what you're trying to do so a better suggestion can be provided.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: yes I would like to use the UITableViewDelegates however they are already being used by the tableview that is also in this view. please check my edited question for an explanation on what I am trying to achive.

Comment: Is there a reason you need more than one TableView in one view?

Comment: I have added  to my question at the bottom a edit to what I am trying to achieve. its because I want a main cell at the top that the tableview scrolls behind if the user cannot find something they wish to select they can choose to @"select all"

Comment: I see. If it's only one cell and you want it locked at the top, I wouldn't use a UITableView for it.  Just make it a regular UIView and position the UITableView below it.  Now if you want that cell to scroll within the UITableView, you could probably just put it in another section and use a custom header or footer.

Comment: If that still doesn't work, and you must have two table views, you can still point them to the same delegate.  Since you get a UITableView* with didSelectRowAtIndexPath, you can use that to see which UITableView dispatched the selection event.

Comment: okay your second to last comment could be a possibility, I have read you can have a custom UITableView Header... is it possible to then select this header? or how would I handle it?.. I just changed my tableviewcell to a UIButton this works okay, however if there is a better way of doing it I'm still intrested.